# Shortening text height across chapter to fill last page

Tags: packages, widows-orphans, grid-typesetting

We all know the problem of having a chapter that is just too large to fill the last page conveniently, leaving one or two (or three) lines at the top of the last page.

Besides attempting feats of text compression, which may or not feasibly produce elegant results, one attractive solution to this problem is to shorten the text height of previous pages in the chapter by a single line, generating enough material to give the last page some company.

Are there solutions (perhaps in packages) which allow TeX accomplish this automatically?

Comment: The issue here will be similar to your other question. TeX does not process the entire chapter in one go. It goes page-by-page (or page-plus-a-bit--by--page-plus-a-bit). So TeX cannot know it needs to shorten the height until after the point at which this would be effective. At least, I think so.

Comment: @cfr Makes sense. I assumed that this would take at least two passes, so this limitation is not necessarily binding. And then there's the question of whether we could compensate for this using appropriate scripting in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @JohnPeyton You can play with orphans and widows and also with the space between paragraphs for get the right layout and number of pages (something critical for printed books). Also you can adjust the margins or test different typographies even if you don't need to adjust a very rigid layout that avoid you the exercise of those freedoms.

Comment: Another option used when typesetting is to edit the content.

Comment: Alternatively, stick a \vfil\pagebreak[3] between every paragraph and see if you can expand to fill one more page. ;-)